# How do I force redraw of canvas api using js?

Tags: html5-canvas

How do I force a redraw of [canvas api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) ?

I have a js button  which I want to force a redraw when clicking.

It only redraws after I hover on the canvas.

Have access to canvas and ctx in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for certain without seeing your code but I think you could simply take the function being called in the canvas `onhover` and use that same function for your button using the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: cool idea! I found a work around, but will keep it in mind. I mean maybe I can call `canvas.onhover()` too